# Getting the underlying data in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

The data representation was created in Tableau and I am accessing and showing it on my website through the Tableau JS API: [link to the API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm).

Obtaining the `viz` and showing my Tableau have already been done. I have a Bar Chart showing my data in horizontal columns. The idea is that I want to be able to click on a column and then get the data which goes into this column.

Let's say we have 12 elements. They are represented by 3 columns. The first column has 5, the second 3 and the third 4 elements. In my case, after selecting the column with 4 elements I would want to be able to get the underlying 4 data entries.

I have been going through the API Documentation ([link](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm)) and I have added on click listener for `marksSelection`. However, it only returns me the "sorting conditions" so to say. I tried getting the `getUnderlyingDataAsync` and then `getData()` but the returned data is not really in a format which I can use (since there are only pairs of row and column and not the full data entries).

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in a couple of steps following the [API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_ref.htm):

1. `getUnderlyingDataAsync` to obtain a `DataTable`, save it to an object called `dataTable`.
2. Get all of the (raw) data by calling `dataTable.getData()`. It returns a 2D array. To help you imagine the structure, let's say that the data source has 50 objects then the array will have a length of 50. If each object has 5 properties then the nested array will have a length of 5 (with each property represented as 1 element).
3. Get all of the columns by calling `dataTable.getColumns()`. Here you will need the `name` and `index` properties.
4. Create an object containing our actual `JSON` data by combining the columns in (3) and the (raw) data from (2).

Now you should have a structured array of objects.